# Code base protect at demarsheling time

Tags: marshalling, rmi, rpc

According to wiki

[Marshalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29)

marshalling an object includes codebase and object data. If codebase i.e. source code of class of an object is transferred to another machine , how can it be protected to be viewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If codebase i.e. source code of class of an object is transferred to another machine

It isn't. That isn't what 'codebase' means. The 'codebase' of a class is information about where the .class file was loaded from. Don't just guess what words mean, look them up.

Comment: I had done some homework on Codebase :
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codebase
As the link emphasizes on "Source code" that is why question struck my mind.

Comment: Wikipedia's fault. Not an ambiguity you would have found in the official Java documentation. I've fixed Wikipedia.